# How to use a Random Expression again in Tosca?

Tags: selenium, testing, random, automation, tosca

I am working on Tosca tool and I want to know, How to reuse an random expression value again in another step but in the same test case?
Example: I have given a random expression for mail I'd and I would like to use that randomly generated mail again

Answer (score 2):

You could create and buffer the random expression and use the buffer value at any point in your testcase

Comment: I'd have said the same. @Kausal be careful though, when using random in automation you have to make sure that you know how to find out which values were used (otherwise you may not be able to reproduce a failure)